# Why is this sql not injected

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I have this HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="display.php">
    Enter First Name:<input type="name" name="fname"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Show details" name="submit">
</form>
```

I have this SQL query

```
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","school");
$sql= "SELECT * FROM class1 where fname=$fname";    

//print_r($sql);

if($db->query($sql)) {  
    echo "Success query!";
} else {
    echo "Error occurred!";
}
```

I am practicing SQL injection here. I have tried this: `roger; DROP TABLE class1;--`  but it doesn't work out. even `roger OR 1=1` in the input is not working.

Comment: What means `not working`? What is happend?

Comment: Simply, before trying to inject some SQL instructions, run the script with a a simple proper value and check if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli::query()` will not execute multiple queries. You have to use `$db->multi_query($sql)` and it will accept multiple queries separated by `;`.

Also, if the input is `roger or 1=1`, you'll get an error because the table has no column named `roger`. The input needs to have quotes: `'roger' or 1=1`.